# Advice for fixing my countdowntimer in android

Tags: java, android, countdowntimer

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private CountDownTimer countDownTimer;
private CountDownTimer countDownTimer2;//second timer count down

private boolean timerStart = false;//timer start
private boolean timerStart2 = false;

private Button startButton;//timer button
private Button startButton2;

public TextView text;
public TextView text2;//text field for second timer

public TextView text3;// text 3 and 4 meant to hold the elapsed time for each timer
public TextView text4;

private final long startTime = 90 * 1000;//first timer
private final long interval = 1 * 1000;

private final long startTime2 = 30 * 1000; //second timer time
private final long interval2 = 1 * 1000;

TextToSpeech tts;

private class countDownTimerListener implements OnClickListener {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (!timerStart){
            countDownTimer.start();
            timerStart = true;
            startButton.setText("Stop");
            startButton2.setEnabled(false);
        } else {
            countDownTimer.cancel();
            timerStart = false;
            startButton.setText("Restart");             
        }                   
    }       
}
private class countDownTimerListener2 implements OnClickListener {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (!timerStart2){
            countDownTimer2.start();
            timerStart2 = true;
            startButton2.setText("Stop");
            startButton.setEnabled(false);
        } else {
            countDownTimer2.cancel();
            timerStart2 = false;
            startButton2.setText("Restart");
        }                   
    }       
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    startButton = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.button1);
    startButton2 = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.button2);

    startButton.setOnClickListener(new countDownTimerListener());
    startButton2.setOnClickListener(new countDownTimerListener2());

    text = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    text2 = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.textView4);//second timer text

    text3 = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.textView5);//text field for elapsed time
    text4 = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.textView7);
    //this is where I take the text view from xml and assign to text 3 and 4.
    countDownTimer = new MyTimer(startTime, interval, "You have completed your 90 second Timer", text, text3);//first timer
    text.setText(text.getText() + String.valueOf(startTime/1000));

    countDownTimer2 = new MyTimer(startTime2, interval2, "You have completed your 30 second Timer", text2, text4);//second timer start
    text2.setText(text2.getText() + String.valueOf(startTime2/1000));//second timer text field

    tts = new TextToSpeech(getApplicationContext(), new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() {

        @Override
        public void onInit(int status) {
            if(status != TextToSpeech.ERROR){
                tts.setLanguage(Locale.US);
            }
        }                           
    });
}

public class MyTimer extends CountDownTimer { 
    private String ttsString;
    private TextView textview;
    private TextView timeElapsedView;
    private long timeElapsed;
    private long startTime;

    public MyTimer(long startTime, long interval, String ttsString, TextView textview, TextView timeElapsedView){
        super(startTime, interval);
        this.ttsString = ttsString;
        this.textview = textview;
        this.timeElapsedView = timeElapsedView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        textview.setText("" + (millisUntilFinished / 1000));
        //startTime - millisUntilFinished elapsed time
        timeElapsed = ((startTime - millisUntilFinished) / 1000);
        timeElapsedView.setText("" + String.valueOf(timeElapsed));
    }

    @Override
    public void onFinish() {
        textview.setText("Time's up!"); 
        //Vibrator vibrator = (Vibrator)this.getSystemService(VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
        //vibrator.vibrate(600);
        ToneGenerator toneG = new ToneGenerator(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM, 100);
        toneG.startTone(ToneGenerator.TONE_CDMA_ALERT_CALL_GUARD, 200);
        tts.speak(ttsString, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, null);     
    }
}
```

}

I'm am trying to create a countdown timer in Java for android. I want it to show the elapsed time, starting from 1, and the remaining time counting down. I can get the countdown time to work fine but when I do elapsed time, it starts from 89971 and counts up from there. Any advice on how to fix this? This is the code I have that I am using for the timer to appear.

Comment: this is not the full code either, it is only about half. If anyone needs more I can post the other half

Comment: Is startTime smaller than (millisecUntilFinished / 1000)?  Won't that result in a negative number that increase as you subtract less and less with each tick?

Comment: In line `textview.setText("" + millisUntilFinished / 1000);` you should change for `textview.setText("" + (millisUntilFinished / 1000));` Note the ( and ) between `millisUntilFinished / 1000`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where does your `startTime` within the `onTick()` method come from? If it's an instance-variable of your `MyTimer`-class, you have forgotten to mention that. Furthermore, it's a long, a time-value in milliseconds just as the `millisInFuture`-value. That means, you should do something like this:

```
timeElapsed = (startTime - millisUntilFinished) / 1000;
```

And you can make `timeElapsed` a local variable of the `onTick()`-method.

Update after disclosure of full code:

Please add a `startTime` instance variable to your `MyTimer`-class, which you initialize properly in the `MyTimer`-constructor, because you use MyTimer in two places with two different start times, but in `onTick()`, you use the `startTime` instance variable from the outer class, which is only valid for the first instance (`countDownTimer`).

Comment: Yes startTime is an instance variable. It is set up in the main activity in my code.

Comment: Hey, your solution worked except now it is starting at 60 and counting up. Any advice to fix that? I want it to start from 0.

Comment: For that, your full code is required. Otherwise, it would be pure guess-work, which would help no one and only eat up time. Please edit your post above to show the full code, then I can adjust my answer.

Comment: Please see my adjusted answer.

Comment: I added private long startTime under the timeElapsed under the MyTimer class

Comment: As I already said, `timeElapsed` should better be method-local. Is your sixty-second problem gone now, even without the -59 hack? Because actually, right now, I cannot see a reason for it, but as I only look at the code, and don't actually run/debug it, I might miss something. If it's not gone, you should use a debugger to identify that problem.

Comment: what is happening now after taking off -59 is that when I run the first timer (90 second one) it counts up from 0, but if I run the second one (30 second timer), it will start at -30 and count up, so it ends at 0 when the timer is finished.

Comment: Do you have this line in your `MyTimer`-constructor, as well? `this.startTime = startTime;`

Comment: OK, after adding that line, it now works perfectly. Thank you!